# Get user input and check it, linux

Tags: shell, if-statement, unix, while-loop

I am a beginner at unix and I am trying to use a while loop to get a user integer input for 2 numbers, but I need to check if it is an integer and reask if it's not, so I attempted to utilize if statements inside the while loop. I cannot get this to work, what am I doing wrong with the while and if loop?
       #! /bin/bash

```
    echo “Enter first number:“

    while read number1
    do
      if[[ $number1 ]] && [ $input -eq $input 2>/dev/null ]
      then 
        echo “$number1”

      else
        echo "$number1 is not an integer or not defined.Try again”
      fi
     done


    echo “Enter second number:“
    while read number2
       do
        if[[ $number2 ]] && [ $input -eq $input 2>/dev/null ]
            then 
              echo “$number2”
        else
              echo "$number2 is not an integer or not defined.Try again”
         fi
    done
```

Comment: Please include in your question the mandatory four:  ① What did you try, ② what did you expect to happen, ③ what did you observe instead, and ④ why is this not matching your expectation.  You provided ① and ②.

Comment: Check your spaces (always around `[[` and `]]`) and your quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the number and checking it until it becomes integer, Please try the below code.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter number"
while read number1
do
if ! [[ $number1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
        echo "number is not an integer"

else
        echo "number is an integer"
        exit;
fi
done
```